# Can you fit smaller sized structures into a larger chunk of memory?

Tags: c, memory, data-structures, malloc

I have this structure:

```
typedef struct
{
int data[10];
} small_structure;
```

and this code:

```
small_structure *s_struct;
void * chunk;

chunk = malloc(1000);
s_struct = chunk;
```

Is it ok to do something like this? Ignore the fact that this is wasting memory.

Comment: Are you trying to do the [struct hack](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.  `malloc` will return you suitably aligned memory.  Just assigning any arbitrary `void *` pointer to a `small_structure *` variable is *not* OK, however.  That means your specific example is fine, but something like:

```
int function(void *p)
{
    small_structure *s = p;
    return s->data[0];
}
```

is not!  If `p` isn't suitably aligned for a `small_structure *` pointer, you've just caused undefined behaviour.

Comment: Whats wrong with using the void pointer as an in between? For example, I have a 2nd structure: (large_structure * l_struct) which is still smaller than the chunk of memory, and after I am done using s_struct, I assign l_struct = chunk and then begin using l_struct.

Comment: @ZPS: It's not fine in general, but is fine if you know that your alignment will always be correct.

Comment: Gabe's got it right.  In my function example, you can't know that `s` is correctly aligned.  Your original example in your question is fine, though.  I just wanted to caution against dangerous behaviour when playing with `void *`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is always legal to allocate more memory than you need, so long as that much memory is available.

Answer (score 2):

AFAICT, there is nothing wrong with it (except for the waste ;-).

Note that you'll have to fill the struct with useful data before you use it.